# A good strategy to store units of measurement in Core Data in iOS project

Tags: ios, core-data, localization, units-of-measurement

I am writing an application that keep track of length and height of a certain item. In essence, I would like to make the app to support both metric and imperial measurement system. My current strategy is to store a certain measurement data into Core Data, and come up with a specific object that would calculate and convert between these 2 systems before displaying the  data on the screen.

However, since iOS has great support on localization, I wonder if there should be a better way than writing my own unit converter?

Comment: Did you ever find a good answer to this?  I'm facing a similar question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Store one of either metric or imperial (personally I'd use metric), then just create an accessor for each.

```
- (NSString *)metricUnitsString
{
   // format your string.
   return formattedString;
}

- (NSString *)imperialUnitsString
{
   // convert value to imperial units.
   // format your string.
   return formattedString;
}
```

If you want to present the string depending on the user's locale, you can query `[NSLocale currentLocale]` and check the value for `NSLocaleMeasurementSystem`.

[NSLocaleMeasurementSystem](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSLocale_Class/Reference/Reference.html):

> The key for the measurement system associated with the locale. The
>   corresponding value is an NSString object containing a description of
>   the measurement system used by the locale, for example “Metric” or
>   “U.S.”.

Comment: NSLocalecMeasurementSystem is exactly what I am looking for. Thanks!